# How do I change all the character values of a column that starts with specific characters?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with millions of observations.

One of the columns of this dataset uses 4 or 5 characters to classify these observations.

My goal is to merge this classification into smaller groups, for example, I want to replace all the values of the column that STARTS with "AA" (e.g., "AABC" or "AAUCC") for just "A". How can I do this?

To illustrate:

Considering that my data is labeled "f2016" and the column that I'm interested in is "SECT16", I've been using the following code to replace values:

**`f2016$SECT16[f2016$SECT16 == "AABB"] <- "A"`**

But I cannot do this to all combinations of letters that I have in the dataset. Is there a way that I can do the same replacement holding the first two letters constant?

Comment: You probably need `substr()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `base R` solution:

```
f2016[startsWith(f2016$SECT16, "AA"),] <- "A"
#   SECT16
# 1      A
# 2      A
# 3 ABBBBC
# 4  DDDDE
# 5   BABA
```

This replaces `chars` with the prefix specified in this case `AA`.  An an excerpt from from the `help(startsWith)`.

> startsWith() is equivalent to but **much faster than**
>
> substring(x, 1, nchar(prefix)) == prefix
>
> or also
>
> grepl("^", x)
>
> where prefix is not to contain special regular expression characters.

## Data

```
f2016 <- data.frame(SECT16 = c("AAABBB", "AAAAAABBBB", "ABBBBC", "DDDDE", "BABA"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep`/`grepl`

```
f2016$SECT16[grep("^AA", f2016$SECT16)] <- "A"
#f2016$SECT16[grepl("^AA", f2016$SECT16)] <- "A"
```

Consider this dataset

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("ABCD", "AACD", "DASDD", "AABB"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#      A
#1  ABCD
#2  AACD
#3 DASDD
#4  AABB
df$A[grep("^AA", df$A)] <- "A"


df
#      A
#1  ABCD
#2     A
#3 DASDD
#4     A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringr` and `dplyr`.

Modify all columns:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_all(function(x) stringr::str_replace(x, "^AA.+", "A"))
```

Modify specific columns:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_at(1, function(x) stringr::str_replace(x, "^AA.+", "A"))
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(SECT16 = c("AABC", "AABB"),
           SECT17 = c("AADD", "AAEE"))
```